# Exception safety and concurrency in C++11 and beyond: guidelines for STL implemented functions

Tags: c++11, exception, concurrency

I am currently learning to handle concurrency in C++11 and beyond. As a reference, I chose a book called "C++ concurrency in action" which mentions that, when one designs parallel algorithms for, say, implementing a parallel accumulation of elements in a container, careful attention must be paid to the exception safety. Specifically, that the current struct:

```
template<typename Iterator,typename T>
struct accumulate_block
{
    void operator()(Iterator first,Iterator last,T& result)
    {
result=std::accumulate(first,last,result);
    }
};
```

if called upon in the below parallel function:

```
template<typename Iterator,typename T>
T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first,Iterator last,T init)
{
  // some code....
std::vector<T> results(num_threads);
std::vector<std::thread>  threads(num_threads-1);
Iterator block_start=first;
for(unsigned long i=0;i<(num_threads-1);++i)
    {
        Iterator block_end=block_start;
        std::advance(block_end,block_size);
        threads[i]=std::thread(
            accumulate_block<Iterator,T>(),
            block_start,block_end,std::ref(results[i]));
        block_start=block_end;
    }

 // more code...

}
```

It is argued that such code is not exception-safe **because** std::accumulate in the struct might throw, and proposes to use packaged_tasks and std::futures to haul exceptions between threads, rather than the above implementation.

My point is: how can I gauge which methods in the STL will throw, and how does "hauling" them inside futures and packaged_tasks make them any safer?

Thanks

Amine

Comment: I think I understand it a bit better: unless one is absolutely certain that the function spawned in the thread will not throw, it is always better to wrap in std::future or task because these carry back the exceptions to the caller, whereas just wrapping it in a std::thread will terminate the program. Please advise if my understanding is correct. thanks

Comment: Note that many standard algorithms could be implemented to use simple operations that might be overloaded. For example `std::accumulate` probably uses plain addition, and if `operator+` is overloaded for the types in the collection,  the overloaded function might throw. You need to look for `noexcept` or `noexcept(true)` for functions that should not cause exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for this. I realised that after posting my question...

I guess therefore that using std::future or tasks is almost always a cleaner way of propagating exceptions in multi threaded environments, and will keep using raw threads to the minimum.